# Dockerfile Mysql - Errors were encountered while processing

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

i'm trying to install mysql in my docker application but i'm facing with an error in my Dockerfile when running "docker-compose build".

**My docker-compose.yml :**

```
services:

  database:
    container_name: mysql_database  
    build: ./docker/mysql
    command: --max_allowed_packet=256M
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_CHARSET: utf8
      MYSQL_COLLATION: utf8
```

**My Dockerfile:**

```
FROM mysql:5.7

# Install packages
RUN apt-get update --yes && apt-get install --yes procps
RUN apt-get install --yes \
    apt-utils \
    curl \
    git \
    htop \
    man \
    mlocate \
    mysql-client \
    zlib1g-dev \
    zip \
    unzip \
    vim \
    wget

COPY root/.vimrc /root/.vimrc
COPY root/.bashrc /root/.bashrc

WORKDIR /var/lib/mysql
```

**ERROR displayed :**

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-community-server
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
ERROR: Service 'database' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install --yes     apt-utils     curl     git     htop     man     mlocate     mysql-client     zlib1g-dev     zip     unzip     vim     wget' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

What's wrong with my config or commands ?

Comment: I would insert an upgrade into your first command, so make it `apt-get update --yes && apt-get upgrade --yes && apt-get install --yes procps`. This means you are working from a latest release.

Comment: If that does not help, stick with it anyway, and then temporarily trim your second list of software until something reveals that it is the problem. Narrow down what that is. Maybe you have used the wrong name for an installable item.

Comment: Now i have, `Errors were encountered while processing:
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-8rvoCi/2-mysql-community-server_5.7.29-1debian9_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
ERROR: Service 'database' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update --yes && apt-get upgrade --yes' returned a non-zero code: 100`

Comment: Why do you need `htop`, `git`, `man`, `vim`, or shell dotfiles to run a database?  Why can't you run the unmodified `mysql:5.7` database image?

Comment: You could try do `apt-get install -yq` the packages individually to see wich one is causing you trouble. Particularly I would install the mysql-client in an command alone because of Its size.

Comment: @David, actually, it's a project i work in my company and you are right `htop`, `git`, `man` are not useful here but shell dotfiles are used to style command line. After removing packages i don't need, i have now new errors line `debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (TERM is not set, so the dialog frontend is not usable.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Readline
debconf: (This frontend requires a controlling tty.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Teletype
dpkg-preconfigure: unable to re-open stdin:`

Comment: After that, I have the same error : 
`dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-community-server
 mysql-server`

Comment: It works by removing the package `mysql-client` in my dockerfile and using the unmodified `mysql:5.7` as @DavidMaze said. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the problem you have, as per your latest comment updates, is not reproducible. It works fine for me.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mysql:5.7

RUN apt-get update --yes && apt-get upgrade --yes
```

Build command:

```
docker build -t docker-build-test .
```

Output:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/2 : FROM mysql:5.7
5.7: Pulling from library/mysql
123275d6e508: Pull complete 
27cddf5c7140: Pull complete 
c17d442e14c9: Pull complete 
5fc78b1e06f8: Pull complete 
cd38802f42bb: Pull complete 
b370e336f220: Pull complete 
f519d6d4d2f6: Pull complete 
93fcd48f8a46: Pull complete 
52b3f78c0999: Pull complete 
0692e317044b: Pull complete 
bdf7d9d2736f: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:7924ec534b844f9c7c0547fa95265516e8adf19ca475cffe911202037392d264
Status: Downloaded newer image for mysql:5.7
 ---> 66371c06f4ca
Step 2/2 : RUN apt-get update --yes && apt-get upgrade --yes
 ---> Running in 6c6b003973ad
Get:1 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian buster InRelease [21.5 kB]
Get:2 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease [65.4 kB]
Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease [122 kB]
Get:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease [49.3 kB]
Get:5 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian buster/mysql-5.7 amd64 Packages [5680 B]
Get:6 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/main amd64 Packages [187 kB]
Get:7 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 Packages [7907 kB]
Get:8 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates/main amd64 Packages [7380 B]
Fetched 8365 kB in 23s (369 kB/s)
Reading package lists...
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Calculating upgrade...
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Removing intermediate container 6c6b003973ad
 ---> e50d1485ef7f
Successfully built e50d1485ef7f
Successfully tagged docker-build-test:latest
```

This build is successful. Could you amend your question, and pare the Dockerfile back to the smallest possible failing case? It may also be worth adding your host OS and Docker version number too.

Comment: @AshadKhan: I just got a shell on this container `docker run -it docker-build-test bash` and then ran the client `mysql` successfully without installing anything further. In other words, that might be your problem - the client is already installed in this image.